# How to fully maximize window in Xubuntu by dragging title bar to top edge?

Tags: window-management, xubuntu

In Xubuntu 12.10, I am able to drag a window title bar to the top of the screen and it will maximize, but it will only maximize the top half of the display. Is there a way so it maximizes to the full screen like in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is no, this feature does not exist in Xfce 4.10

You could:

- maximize the window by double clicking on the window header
- use keyboard short-cut:

Alt+F5 Maximize current Width

Alt+F6 Maximize current Height

Alt+F9 Minimize current window.

Alt+F10 Maximize the current window.

Or create your own shortcut using the **Window Manager** in the settings

I found this: [LINK](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8071)

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna give a late answer to this thread as I had the same problem for a good while before I found a nice solution. I'm on Xubuntu 14.04.

I installed Kwin, the window manager from KDE desktop. Everything works perfectly and windows tile to sides, corners, and maximize when draged to the top. Do:

```
sudo apt-get kde-window-manager
```

Try it with `kwin --replace`. Then go to `settings manager > Session and startup > Applicaiton Autostart > +Add`

Input whatever in the first two fields and in the last one put

```
kwin --replace
```

Save and log out and in again. Now you have the expected window tiling and OpenGL acceleration giving less tearing. You will get new window decorations. To change window manager settings, you can right click the title bar and choose `More actions > window manager settings`. In those settings go to Focus and set focus stealing prevention to none for the cursor to appear in the whisker menu, i.e. the regular XFCE menu, when pressing Ctrl+Esc or whatever key you bound to it.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is added to Xfce 4.12.

Open terminal and type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/extras

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04...