# Xubuntu - Maximize window instead of top half on snap up

Tags: xubuntu, window, snap-windows

I want to maximize window instead of making it fill the top half of the screen on snap up. I can't find how to change it in settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/224329/how-to-fully-maximize-window-in-xubuntu-by-dragging-title-bar-to-top-edge) being asked already, with answers, but without any confirmation from the asker.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, you can't.

There isn't anything relevant to be changed in the Settings Manager or Settings Editor, assuming that you are using Xubuntu release that still uses Xfce 4.10 or earlier (Xubuntu 14.04 or older).

The long answer is, you can get it with some efforts.

There are two known ways to achieve this, based on the clues left in the answer given in the similar question that is linked in comment above.

1. Modify the source code of xfwm4 according to [this forum post](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=32441#p32441) and recompile it
2. Upgrade your existing Xfce to version 4.12, either by:

   a. using [Xubuntu Dev PPA (deprecated)](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xfce-4.12) to upgrade

   b. downloading stable packages, [compile and install manually](https://askubuntu.com/a/612382/37165)

   c. upgrading to Xubuntu 15.04 that also comes with Xfce 4.12

If you are using Xubuntu 14.04 or 14.10, the easiest method is probably method 2a, using PPA to upgrade. However, it has been noted as "with no guarantee of functionality or support". Several known issues can be read from [this article](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/install-xfce-412-in-xubuntu-1404-or.html).

Above all, I have compiled the resources into this single answer for convenience and it is for you to decide whichever method you prefer to achive "maximize window on snap-up" feature.

---

**Answerer's note**: This answer was relevant at time of posting, but is now deprecated. The newer releases of Xubuntu does maximize window as expected and this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by clearkimura is an excellent one. However, I resolved this by going to Window Manager Tweaks and deselecting 'Automatically tile windows..' I use three monitors. When I drag a maximized window to a new screen, I noticed it will fill the window when I drag cursor to the top. Otherwise, I double click the window header to maximize. Then if I want to tile left and right I set a keyboard shortcut under Window Manager Tweaks > Keyboard > Tile window. I ended up being fine with this setup. It probably makes a big difference too that I have multiple monitors. I may not be as content with this if I just had one monitor. The only exception to this I've noticed is that Chrome (not Chromium) does not maximize in this way. I have used Xfce 4.12 on Fedora 22 and on Xubuntu 15.04, and it has worked well. However, I don't know how well it would work on 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

This is the third thread I'm answering this question on tonight, but I searched long for the solution so I feel like sharing. I'm on Xubuntu 14.04.

I installed Kwin, the window manager from KDE desktop. Everything works perfectly and windows tile to sides, corners, and maximize when dragged to the top. Do:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-window-manager
```

Try it with `kwin --replace`. Then go to `settings manager > Session and startup > Applicaiton Autostart > +Add`

Input whatever in the first two fields and in the last one put

```
kwin --replace
```

Save and log out and in again. Now you have the expected window tiling and OpenGL acceleration giving less tearing. You will get new window decorations. To change window manager settings, you can right click the title bar and choose `More actions > window manager settings`. In those settings go to `Focus` and set `focus stealing prevention` to `none` for the cursor to appear in the `whisker menu`, i.e. the regular XFCE menu, when pressing Ctrl+Esc or whatever key you bound to it.